# Dictionary that has shifted values

Tags: python, dictionary, ordereddictionary

I have to define a function that shifts dictionary key values by n=1.

For example:

```
input :  {'A' : 'A', 'B' : 'B', 'C' : 'C'} 

output : {'A' : 'B', 'B' : 'C', 'C' : 'A'}
```

This is what I have tried:

```
dictionary = {'A' : 'A', 'B' : 'B', 'C' : 'C'}

def shift(dictionary, n):
    n=1
    for i in range (0,int(len(dictionary)/2)):    
        dictionary[list(dictionary)[i]], dictionary[list(dictionary)[len(dictionary)-i-1]] = dictionary[list(dictionary)[len(dictionary)-i-1]], dictionary[list(dictionary)[i]]

    return shift
```

Can someone explain to me have to shift by n=1, I only know how to change value to be random, not to be exactly moved by one.

Comment: But what is `n` for? You don't use it anywhere. Also note that, prior to Python 3.6, dictionaries are un-ordered.

Comment: Change `int(len(dictionary)/2)` to `len(dictionary) // 2`.  This performs integer division, without the need to convert to/from floating point.

Comment: n is a valuee by which values are shifted

Comment: Is there any connection between the keys and the values?  i.e. does the value `C` wrap back around to `A` because those are the only keys in the dict?

Comment: You need to understand that dictionary entries are *unordered*.  So doing `list(dictionary)` does not produce a predictable order.  And why are you doing it *every time* through the loop?  Do you really want for force O(n**2) time complexity?

Comment: @TomKarzes Dict entries have been guaranteed to be ordered since Python 3.7, and in prior versions you could always use a `collections.OrderedDict` to accomplish the same.

Comment: @blhsing Thanks, I had forgotten that change.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Python 3.7 or later, where dict keys are ordered, you can use `itertools.cycle` with the dict values to allow values to wrap around, and use `itertools.islice` to shift the values by the given number, so that they can be zipped with the keys to construct a new dict with the `dict` constructor:

```
from itertools import cycle, islice
def shift(d, n):
    return dict(zip(d, islice(cycle(d.values()), n, None)))
```

so that `shift({'A' : 'A', 'B' : 'B', 'C' : 'C'}, 1)` returns:

```
{'A': 'B', 'B': 'C', 'C': 'A'}
```

and that `shift({'A' : 'A', 'B' : 'B', 'C' : 'C'}, 2)` returns:

```
{'A': 'C', 'B': 'A', 'C': 'B'}
```

If you're using earlier Python versions, you can use `collections.OrderedDict` in place of dict.